# How to $unset a nested object graph in Mongo and to expose a certain object-graph depth in the projection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

My question pertains to optimising stale data in a nested document using Mongo, I'm using a Java implementation but I don't think that matters.

I used a 'stat' collection to keep track of my minute, monthly, yearly and total stats and each stat has its own document, for example the stat name could be 'memory', or 'requests', whatever.

Here's an example...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b47269748cbb4a1e57d5f0a"),
    "stat" : "my-stat-1",
    "app" : {
        "total" : {
            "total" : NumberLong(15201),
            "yearly" : {
                "2018" : 8396,
                "2019" : NumberLong(6805)
            },
            "monthly" : {
                "Jul 2018" : 306,
                "Aug 2018" : 389,
                "Sep 2018" : 107,
                "Oct 2018" : 6959,
                "Nov 2018" : 532,
                "Dec 2018" : 103,
                "Jan 2019" : 67
            },
            "minutes" : {
                "2019-10-28T15:06" : 1,
                "2019-10-29T15:07" : 1,
                "2019-10-28T15:08" : 2,
                "2019-10-28T15:09" : 3,
                "2019-10-28T15:11" : 2,
                "2019-10-28T15:12" : 2,
                "2019-10-28T15:25" : 3,
                "2019-10-28T15:26" : 9,
                "2019-10-28T15:27" : 2,
                "2019-10-28T16:48" : 5
            }
        },
        "api-1" : {
            "total" : 713,
            "yearly" : {
                "2018" : 187,
                "2019" : 526
            },
            "monthly" : {
                "Jul 2018" : 71,
                "Aug 2018" : 77,
                "Sep 2018" : 3,
                "Nov 2018" : 12,
                "Dec 2018" : 24,
            },
            "minutes" : {}
        },
        "api-2" : {
            "total" : 3490,
            "yearly" : {
                "2018" : 1021,
                "2019" : 2469
            },
            "monthly" : {
                "Jul 2018" : 211,
                "Aug 2018" : 119,
                "Sep 2018" : 37,
                "Oct 2018" : 77,
                "Nov 2018" : 499,
                "Dec 2018" : 78,
                "Jan 2019" : 66,
            },
            "minutes" : {
                "2019-10-28T20:10" : 14,
                "2019-10-28T20:11" : 1,
                "2019-10-28T20:20" : 18,
                "2019-10-28T20:21" : 3,
                "2019-10-28T20:22" : 3,
                "2019-10-30T11:45" : 3,
                "2019-10-30T17:02" : 7,
                "2019-10-30T19:55" : 20
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to keep 'document' focused, by keeping all relevant stats together, I could have used a collection with this sort of structure...

- date (minute granularity)
- statName
- value

But the advantage to my object-based approach was I could easily get my monthly, yearly and total stats with no aggregation, plus I get all my applicable stats back in one nicely package document.

My chart service would simply hook into app.total. and then enumerate the values really quickly - it works well.

The issue is this is a real pain when it comes to deletion of stale minute data (I have no plan to delete the monthly or yearly stats).

I think I made a mistake to store my minute-granularity statistics in an object, rather than an array, but I really, really don't want to change the structure at this time.  I want to learn whether I can work with what I have efficiently.

The advantage to using an object structure for the 'minutes' stat is that I can use the $min and $max update operators to conditionally update the records, for example to only overwrite a statistic if the new value is higher than the eixsting persisted record.  Because there's more than one server and because I didn't want to perform a read first this seemed a nice way of dealing with that.  That's where the pro's seem to stop!

I've always said the minute granularity stats would be help for a maximunm of 2-3 days, so I previously wrote a method that deleted the minutes by iterating over my 'stats' collection, then trying to purge any 'minutes' older than two days.

The problem I found was I couldn't find a way of wildcarding the nested fields to unset, especially when I don't know ahead of time what API keys exist in the document, e.g something like this...

```
db.getCollection("stats").update{},{"$unset":{"app.*.minutes.2019-10-28*",""})
```

I don't know what's in the object until I read the whole damn document, but really I don't want the whole document back just to see what needs deleting.

What would be useful is if I could create a projection to say "find me all the child nodes under app to a maximum depth of one", this would enable me to discover the API names without loading in all the stats.  e.g. something like this...

```
db.getCollection("stats").find({},{"app.*":1})
```

to expose

```
"app.total"
"app.api-1"
"app.api-2"
```

In theory then I could have built up a modify statement that $unset those paths, e.g some sort of field regex (although that doesn't look like it's possible) ...

```
"app.total.minutes.2019-10-28*"
"app.api-1.minutes.2019-10-28*"
"app.api-2.minutes.2019-10-28*"
```

But given the regex issue I might have to hydrate those to $unset a five minute stale period, like this ...

```
"app.total.minutes.2019-10-28T15:01"
"app.total.minutes.2019-10-28T15:02"
"app.total.minutes.2019-10-28T15:03"
"app.total.minutes.2019-10-28T15:04"
"app.total.minutes.2019-10-28T15:05"
```

but then I would have to repeat that for each api key too within the stat collection

My current solution is to load the full "my-stat-1" collection into memory, then I iterate over the 'app' keyset, then iterate over the 'minutes' keyset and if the date is older than 2 days I add it to a list which I then $unset the whole list in one statement.

This is of course inefficient, but without changing the document structure, is there anything else I should consider to optimise the deltion of old minute records generically?

Comment: I saw that you said "without changing the document structure", but I strongly recommend that the document structure change.
With this structure you have each occurrence of minutes is a new field.
In this case, 'minutes' should be an Array, where it would have a field with the date and time and another with the quantity.
In this new structure it would be much, much easier to search and delete what you want.
Another thing I would change would be 'app', which would be an Array with the totals.

Comment: Assuming that you are not changing the document structure (for now), I think we can put together code in few steps based on your "theories": (1) Extract all minutes, e.g., "2019-10-28T20:11" and filter based on a supplied date/range, (2) build a _paths_ array for the fields to be _unset_, e.g., `{ "minute_paths" : [ "app.api-1.minutes.2019-10-28T20:10", "app.api-1.minutes.2019-10-28T20:11", ... ] }`, (3) finally, update each field from the array, e.g., `db.stats.update( { }, { $unset: { "app.api-1.minutes.2019-10-28T20:10" : "" } } )`. Steps 1 and 2 work together. Does it makes sense to you?

Comment: Thanks @Prasad_ I did attempt this approach, but if I have 30 API keys and say a 60 minute period, I end up with 30 x 60 unsets = 1,800.  I currently load the stat document, enumerate the api keys & minutes to reduce this down to say 3 API keys and say only a third of those minutes had stats, e.g. 3 x 33 minutes = 99 unsets instead.  Ideally I want to unset using something more generic without reading/enumerating the stats, but without key-based regex support I don't think it's possible, so I might be forced to go the array route, or just have a flat stat collection akin to a relational table

Comment: @Haruo I am leaning towards using the array, but then the $min and $max doesn't work, therefore I think I'll go the full hog and use a collection that has all the stats flat, like a relational table would, then I can query and delete efficiently (with indexes) and the update $min and $max would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas about an approach where you have an (1) ad-hoc solution, and (2) a new structure.

I will be referring this field below:

```
"minutes" : {
                "2019-10-28T15:06" : 1,
                "2019-10-29T15:07" : 1,
                ...
}
```

In the *ad-hoc* solution:

Replace the "minutes" field with a newer version of it:

```
"minutes" : [
              {
                "date" : ISODate("2019-10-28T00:00:00Z"),
                "counts_by_min" : [
                                    {
                                      "timestamp" : "2019-10-28T20:10",
                                       "count" : 14
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "timestamp" : "2019-10-28T21:11",
                                       "count" : 6
                                    }
                                  ]
               },
               {
                 "date" : ISODate("2019-10-29T00:00:00Z"),
                 "counts_by_min" : [ ...] 
               }
]
```

Things to note are the minutes field is an array with a bucket of timestamps for each day (or this can be a range of dates, as needed). The "timestamp" field and the "count" has the same data from the original document data. Better, if the timestamp is also a date field.

Now, (1) how do we get the data into the collection, and (2) how do we process it ? How does this help?

The processing aspect will become simpler (see sample code below).

The way to get data into the collection and how to use it with other applications, I cannot say; I don't have any information related to that. But, I suggest, introduce this new "minutes" field, in parallel (along with the existing version), and work with the rest of the application(s) to apply in phases. I guess it will be some kind of transition.

---

**The Process:**

The query will require a date input based on which the "minutes" data will be removed from the input documents.

**The input document** (based on the posted original one; omitting some fields):

```
   {
        "_id" : 1,
        "stat" : "my-stat-1",
        "app" : {
                "total" : {
                        "monthly" : {
                                "Jul 2018" : 306
                        },
                        "minutes" : [ ]
                },
                "api-1" : {
                        "monthly" : {
                                "Jul 2018" : 71
                        },
                        "minutes" : [
                                {
                                        "date" : ISODate("2019-10-28T00:00:00Z"),
                                        "counts_by_min" : [
                                                {
                                                        "timestamp" : "2019-10-28T20:10",
                                                        "count" : 14
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "timestamp" : "2019-10-28T21:11",
                                                        "count" : 6
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                {
                                        "date" : ISODate("2019-10-29T00:00:00Z"),
                                        "counts_by_min" : [
                                                {
                                                        "timestamp" : "2019-10-29T20:10",
                                                        "count" : 14
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                }
        }
}
```

**The input date and the query:**

Note the query update's the original document. And, the query runs from the shell.

```
var MINS_FILTER = ISODate("2019-10-28T00:00:00Z");

db.stats3.aggregate( [
  { $addFields: { app: { $objectToArray: "$app" } } },
  { $unwind: "$app" },
  { $addFields: { "app.v.minutes": { $filter: {
                                                input: "$app.v.minutes",
                                                as: "mins",
                                                cond: { $ne: [ "$$mins.date", MINS_FILTER ] }
  } } } },
  { $group: { _id: { stat: "$stat", _id: "$_id" }, app: { $push: { k: "$app.k", v: "$app.v" } } } },
  { $addFields: { _id: "$_id._id", stat: "$_id.stat", app: { $arrayToObject: "$app" } } },
]).forEach( doc => db.stats3.save(doc) );
```

**The updated document** in the collection has the day's ( `ISODate("2019-10-28T00:00:00Z")` ) data removed.

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "app" : {
                "total" : {
                        "monthly" : {
                                "Jul 2018" : 306
                        },
                        "minutes" : [ ]
                },
                "api-1" : {
                        "monthly" : {
                                "Jul 2018" : 71
                        },
                        "minutes" : [
                                {
                                        "date" : ISODate("2019-10-29T00:00:00Z"),
                                        "counts_by_min" : [
                                                {
                                                        "timestamp" : "2019-10-29T20:10",
                                                        "count" : 14
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                }
        },
        "stat" : "my-stat-1"
}
```

---

**Note on Design:**

The ***Bucket design pattern*** uses the concept of grouping data together into "buckets". This is very useful in IoT applications. It is also specific to MongoDB's flexible schema data and its design. I think it is relevant to your situation, in case you are planning to restructuring data.

More info here: [Bucket design pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern).